# How to display rows with no count aggregate result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which contains Job, City and PersonName **(who works in that city)**. I want to return all jobs and cities even if there is no one working in that city. This is a simple example :

**Creation of the table :**

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    Job varchar(50),
    City varchar(50),
    PersonName varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES 
    ('Teacher', 'New-York', 'John')
    ,('Teacher', 'Los-Angeles', 'Mary')
    ,('Fireman', 'New-York', 'Sam')
```

**My Query**

```sql
SELECT 
    [Job]
    , [City]
    ,COUNT(PersonName) AS NumberOfPeopleWorkingThere
FROM #Data 
GROUP BY [Job], [City]
ORDER BY [Job], [City]
```

**My result**

```
Fireman    New-York      1
Teacher    Los-Angeles   1
Teacher    New-York      1
```

**But I would like to have :**

```
Fireman    Los-Angeles   0    -> this row in addition
Fireman    New-York      1
Teacher    Los-Angeles   1
Teacher    New-York      1
```

I have no clue how to do this, could you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

Use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join`:

```
SELECT j.job, c.city,
       COUNT(PersonName) AS NumberOfPeopleWorkingThere
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT job FROM #Data) j CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT city FROM #Data) c LEFT JOIN
     #Data d
     ON d.job = j.job AND d.city = c.city
GROUP BY j.job, c.city
ORDER BY j.job, c.city;
```

Comment: I will udpate my question to be more precise because my example was a bit too simple...
Thanks for your first suggestion, I hope you can help me further...

Comment: @ordiminnie . . . This answers the question you asked.  It is better to ask a new question rather than invalidating answers.